# What does s_i stands for in OpenCV findHomography() function?

Tags: opencv, geometry, homography, homogenous-transformation

The [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography) of `findHomography()` states that the transformation this function estimates is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [opencv.org](http://docs.opencv.org/_images/math/4f61591c20d759599c049f1d04d6835c1a370b66.png))</sub>

Why is there a `s_i`? What does it stands for?

Shouldn't homography transformation be just `x' = Hx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated later in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?#findhomography):

> Homography matrix is determined up to a scale. Thus, it is normalized so that h_{33}=1.

so `s_i` is the scale.